# sonar XML plugin installation failure in jenkins

Tags: sonarqube, jenkins-plugins, devops

I am getting the following error when I manually try to install sonar-xml-plugin-1.4.1.hpi plugin in jenkins:

```
Error:

Failure -
java.io.IOException: Failed to dynamically deploy this plugin
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$InstallationJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:1383)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob.run(UpdateCenter.java:1161)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.remoting.AtmostOneThreadExecutor$Worker.run(AtmostOneThreadExecutor.java:110)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal dependency specifier META-INF/lib/xml-squid-1.4.1.jar META-INF/lib/jaxen-1.1.4.jar META-INF/lib/xalan-2.7.2.jar META-INF/lib/sslr-core-1.20.jar META-INF/lib/sslr-squid-bridge-2.6.jar META-INF/lib/xercesImpl-2.8.1.jar META-INF/lib/serializer-2.7.2.jar META-INF/lib/sslr-xpath-1.20.jar
    at hudson.PluginWrapper$Dependency.<init>(PluginWrapper.java:218)
    at hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy.createPluginWrapper(ClassicPluginStrategy.java:231)
    at hudson.PluginManager.dynamicLoad(PluginManager.java:483)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$InstallationJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:1379)
    ... 5 more
```

Do i need to install any dependencies first?? or is it something else that I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did you find this file? The [SonarQube XML plugin](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/SonarXML) is a plugin for SonarQube and should be installed on a SonarQube server, not on a Jenkins server.

Comment: Thanks for the direction. After restarting the SonarQube server, it worked.